# Count the number of posts for logged in user in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want a number of posts that logged in user to have

I tried but I don't know how it will work

```
public function limitation()
{
    $limit = 3;
    $ads = User::WithCount('ads')->get();    
}
```

Any help will appericiate

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: It does not display an error, but rather it displays all users with the number of posts made.I just want to have the number of post of the user connected and limit his number of publication

Comment: I don't really get your question but I think you're trying to achieve this. 

$ads = User:withCount('ads')->get()->count();

Comment: My question is how to limit the post number of a connected user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works!!

$limit = 3;

```
   $userId = auth()->user()->id;

  $userPostCountId = User::where('id', $userId);

   $posts=User::withCount('ads')->first(); //Suggest:- it will return post counts
```

along with user details

```
     if ($userId>0) {
         # code...
       if(isset($posts->ads))

       {
       $count = sizeof($posts->ads);

        if ($count>=$limit) {
```

return redirect()->route('ad.index');

```
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up your user-posts relationship correctly like so:

```php
class User {
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Posts')
    }
}
```

then you can get the users posts like so

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$numPosts = $user->posts()->count();
```

Read more about relationships and how to query them here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you defined proper model naming

Also, you have to define a relationship between users and posts

`User Model`

```
public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Posts::class);
}
```

In your controller

```
public function userPosts()
{
    $userId = auth()->user()->id;
    $userPostCount = User::where('id', $userId)->withCount('posts')->first(); //Suggest:- it will return post counts along with user details

    //or auth()->user()->posts()->count() //it will return only post count

    // or if you want to count with post also
    // $userPosts = User::where('id', $userId)->with('posts')->withCount('posts')->first(); // it will return user posts and post counts along with user data

    return $userPostCount; // or $userPosts
}
```

For more information please read: [Laravel eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Please the 'id' represents the identifier of the User? Because it returns this error message to me.
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: it seems like user is not logged in. First, check if `$userId` exists or not

Comment: It displays the number of posts of the logged in user.
And if I try to retrieve the number in a variable and compare it to $ limit

Comment: It displays the number of posts of the logged in user. "ads_count" => 2? when I do dd ($ userPostCount)
And if I try to retrieve the number in a variable and compare it to $ limit

Answer (score 0):

use **skip** and **take** functions

```
$limit = 3;
$ads = User::WithCount('ads')->skip(0)->take($limit)->get();
```